# Não consigo mudar o value de uma opção depois de clicada do componente mui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, react, material-ui

Olá.. tenho um campo de autocomplete, é um componente da biblioteca mui.com, as options trazem nome e cpf de um cliente. A ideia de fazer esse autocomplete assim, é que como pode existir dois clientes com o mesmo nome, o cpf junto iria diferenciar cada um.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao selecionar um cliente, uso o valor do cpf para trazer o restante dos dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E como existe o campo pra cpf, eu quero que depois da option escolhida, a option no input fique somente com o nome da pessoa, pois da forma que está, o cpf está ficando "duplicado" e isso não fica legal esteticamente.

Consigo pegar o valor da option escolhida, dou um split(' - ') e pego somente o nome, salvo em uma variável e depois atribuo ao value do input, porém de maneira nenhuma esse value troca.

```
const tempInput = document.querySelector('input#buyer-autocomplete');
const tempName =  e.target.innerHTML.split(' - ')[0].trim();
tempInput.value = tempName;
```

se der um console.log em seguida, ta correto, está somente com o nome.. porém não é o que acontece realmente, o input permanece com o value inicial.

Único modo que surtiu alguma troca do input, foi colocando um setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    tempInput.value = tempName;
}, 1000);
```

Porém não é eficaz, ao clicar fora do input ou qualquer outro campo, volta o value inicial.

Segue o código do componente do autocomplete:

```
<Autocomplete
    id="buyer-autocomplete"
    freeSolo={true}
    options={optionsBuyer}
    getOptionLabel={option => `${option.name} - ${(option.cnpjCpf).length === 11 ? cpfMask(option.cnpjCpf) : cnpjMask(option.cnpjCpf)}`}
    onChange={handleInputChange}
    renderInput={params => {
        <TextField
            {...params}
            name='buyer'
            style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
            className={`${classes.autocomplete} notiflix-buyer`}
            label="Cliente"
            onInputChange={handleInputChange}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            {...(errors.client && {
                error: true,
                helperText: <ErrorOutlineIcon className={classes.errorIcon} />
            })} 
        />
    }}/>
```

Procurei na documentação do componente, aqui e em outros lugares, mas não encontrei nada parecido. Se alguém já passou por isso e conseguiu resolver e quiser compartilhar alguma ideia, eu agradeço!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi muito bem todo o seu fluxo, mas tenta fazer algo mais linear.
Por estar usando react acredito que tu poderia remover ou otimizar alguns desses seus códigos.
Sobre o valor do autocomplete, ele precisa ser aplicado do **value**, com o mesmo formato do objeto que está na propriedade **options**.

Esse componente abaixo, funciona perfeitamente, talvez consiga abstrair algo util dele.

```
export default function AutoCompleteComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  function handleChange(event) {
    setValue(event);
  }

  const optionList = [
    { value: 'valor1', label: 'Valor 01' },
    { value: 'valor2', label: 'Valor 02' },
    { value: 'valor3', label: 'Valor 03' },
    { value: 'valor4', label: 'Valor 04' },
    { value: 'valor5', label: 'Valor 05' },
    { value: 'valor6', label: 'Valor 06' },
  ];

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        handleChange(newValue);
      }}
      // inputValue={inputValue}
      options={optionList}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label='Controllable' variant='outlined' />}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe duas props esse componente chamada, `getOptionLabel` a outra é `renderOption`, a optionLabel é o valor que será exibido quando você selecionar uma opção e o renderOption é o valor que será exibido quando a listagem abrir

```
export default function CountrySelect() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="country-select-demo"
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      options={countries}
      autoHighlight
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.nome}
      renderOption={(props, option) => (
       <span>{option.nome}-{option.documento}</span>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          . . .
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Na documentação do MUI tem mais detalhado essa informação. https://mui.com/pt/material-ui/api/autocomplete/